# NodeJs Express-Validator customvalidators doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express-validator customValidators to add some specific validtors:

**middlewares.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
     console.log('to be sure that Im called');
     return function (request, response, next) {
         app.use(expressValidator({
            customValidators: {
                checkObjectId: function(name) {
                    return /^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/.test(name);
                }
            }
         }));
         next();
     }
};
```

**route.js**

```
const middleware = require(__path + '/middlewares');
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    router.use(baseUrl, middleware(app));
    // some codes
    router.put(baseUrl + '/invoice/:invoiceId', api.invoices.invoices.update);
}
```

**invoices.js**

```
    update: (request, response) => {
        // some codes
        request.checkBody('from', 'invalid Supplier Id').checkObjectId();
        // some codes
    },
```

My problem is checkObjectId is not recognized and I have this error:

```
TypeError: request.checkBody(...).checkObjectId is not a function
```

Comment: Could you try implementing checkBody() and checkObjectId() validators separately? I.e. `request.checkBody(...); \n request.checkObjectId(...);`

Comment: I have the same error:
     request.checkObjectId is not a function.
     request.checkObjectId('from.trader', 'invalid Supplier Id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting a function that exports a middleware that declares a middleware.

This should be enough:

```
// middlewares.js
module.exports = expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    checkObjectId: function(name) {
      return /^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/.test(name);
    }
  }
});
```

And to use:

```
const middleware = require(__path + '/middlewares');
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
  router.use(baseUrl, middleware);
  ...
}
```

If you really want to export a function-that-returns-a-middleware, you can use this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  return expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
      checkObjectId: function(name) {
        return /^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/.test(name);
      }
    }
  })
};
```